# How map a shapeless HList of Nat

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a HList of Nat, and I want to map over it

```
object NatToString extends Poly1 {
    implicit def caseNat = at[Nat](_.toString)
}

val list = _5 :: _3 :: HNil
list.map(NatToString)
```

This code doesn't compile and throw:

> could not find implicit value for parameter mapper:
>   shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[Main.Nat_to_String.type,shapeless.::[shapeless.Nat._5,shapeless.::[shapeless.Nat._3,shapeless.HNil]]]

But if I do exactly the same thing with Int (or String, or List, etc.) in place of Nat, it works perfectly.

How can I map over an HList of Nat ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `Poly1.Case` is not covariant in its type parameter. Consider the following:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar extends Foo

val foo = new Foo {}
var bar = new Bar {}

object fooIdentity extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseFoo = at[Foo](identity)
}
```

Now `fooIdentity(foo)` will compile, but `fooIdentity(bar)` won't.

In your case the members of the `HList` are statically typed as `_5` and `_3`. These are subtypes of `Nat`, but `NatToString` doesn't care, since its only case is looking for something statically typed as `Nat`.

The trick is just to add a type parameter to the case:

```
object NatToString extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseNat[N <: Nat] = at[N](_.toString)
}
```

You'll find that in general working with `Nat` directly isn't what you want—you'll almost always want a specific subtype.